# Неверно задано имя папки. Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома. Ошибка при запуске RabbitMQ

Tags: windows, windows-7, rabbitmq

Попытался настроить RabbitMQ пару дней назад. Следовал инструкциям с сайта: https://thewebland.net/development/devops/ustanovka-rabbitmq-na-windows/. Вроде как всё работало и я сделал всё как хотел. Однако сейчас при запуске команды `rabbitmqctl.bat status` в консоли пишется следующее:

```
Неверно задано имя папки.
Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома.
Unsupported node name: hostname is invalid (possibly contains unsupported characters).
If using FQDN node names, use the -l / --longnames argument.
```

Подскажите, что могло измениться за эти несколько дней и почему перестал работать Rabbit?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что вышла новая версия rabbitmq, поэтому старая начала всякие глупости писать. Как только я обновил rabbitmq, всё заработало.